# PUT request data in Symfony2

Tags: rest, symfony, put

The last couple of days I'm trying to build a restful api with Symfony2(2.5 to be precise).  I'm building this api according to best practices most apis follow. Therefor I use a PUT http method for updating a resource. However with the PUT method I'm experiencing a problem. Symfony detects that I'm sending data with the PUT method, but the variables I'm sending are nowhere to be found. Here are some code snippets.

The javascript/jquery ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.adomain.com/app_dev.php/api/account/1',
    type: 'PUT',    
    data: 'name=Sander',
    dataType : 'json',
});
```

The php route in routes.php

```
$collection->add('testbundle_api_update_account', new Route('/api/account/{id}',
array('_controller' => 'TestBundle:Account:apiUpdateAccount'),
array(), array(), '', array(), array('PUT')));
```

The function in the AccountController

```
public function apiUpdateAccountAction($id) {
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    var_dump($request->getRealMethod());
    var_dump($request->request->get('name'));
    var_dump($request->query->get('name'));
    die;
}
```

This outputs

```
string(3) "PUT"
NULL
NULL
```

Everything is working fine. The route is found, the function is called. But where is the send data? Any ideas?

Comment: did you try:  $request = $this->getRequest();   ?

Comment: Yet, don't instanciate a second request instance. Then, it looks like your data is in the request payload. Try doing `$request->getContent()`.

Comment: Yes THANK YOU!!! Touki. That was it :). Not exactly sure why this is, because with get and post you don't have this problem. Maybe it's because the hack "normal" php needs to obtain PUT data. This can only be read once. `parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input', false , null, -1 , $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] ), $_PUT);`

Comment: Whoops, credited the wrong person in my comment. In the answer I credit the correct person John Smith ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by [John Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1712905/john-smith). It probably has to do with the fact that in php PUT data can only be obtained once with;

```
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input', false , null, -1 , $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] ), $_PUT):
```

In Symfony this is probably done before the function in the controller is called. Therefore, the following doesn't work for PUT:

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
```

The following works:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
```

Comment: With sf 2.5, calling <controller>->getRequest()->getContent() doesn't return data from a PUT request, on box where I have verified the client, httpd and php outside of sf2, can receive the data.  I have set the route method correctly.  Is there any other locations that sf2 may have put the data?

Answer (score 1):

difference is

```
var_dump($this->request->getRealMethod());
var_dump($request->request->get('name'));
var_dump($request->query->get('name'));
```

for first working you use

```
$this->request-> ...
```

for not working you use

```
$request->request-> ...
```

try all with $this->request->...

Comment: Sharp :), but that is not causing the problem. In the constructor I set $this->request with Request::createFromGlobals(). For this example code I replaced it(so I thought) with a local variable.